# "Correlation matrix" for strings. Similarity of nominal data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, correlation

Here is my data frame.
    df

```
  store_1      store_2         store_3         store_4     

0 banana      banana           plum            banana
1 orange      tangerine        pear            orange
2 apple       pear             melon           apple
3 pear        raspberry        pineapple       plum
4 plum        tomato           peach           tomato
```

I'm looking for the way to count number of co-occurrences in stores (to compare their similarity).

Comment: I was thinking about using df["store_1"] = df["store_1"].astype('category').cat.codes, but this will assign similar categories to different items in different stores.

Comment: For better explanation: for example: store_1 has 2 intersections with store 2, 2 intersections with store_3 and 4 intersections with store_4... and so on. Looking for the way to count and visualize correspondingly. –

Comment: As the number of "products" across each store in your dataset increases, it may become difficult to visualize this succinctly, unless you apply rules to eliminate low-frequency items. Either way, "grocery stores" (or whatever you're comparing here) have the potential for a high cardinality of offerings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import itertools as it
corr = lambda a,b: len(set(a).intersection(set(b)))/len(a)
c = [corr(*x) for x in it.combinations_with_replacement(df.T.values.tolist(),2)]

j = 0
x = []
for i in range(4, 0, -1): # replace 4 with df.shape[-1]
    x.append([np.nan]*(4-i) + c[j:j+i])
    j+= i
pd.DataFrame(x, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
```

Which yields

```
        store_1 store_2 store_3 store_4
store_1 1.0     0.4     0.4     0.8
store_2 NaN     1.0     0.2     0.4
store_3 NaN     NaN     1.0     0.2
store_4 NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to estimate the similarity of the stores with regards to their products, then you could use:

[One hot encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)

Then each stores can be described by a vector with length of n = number of all products among all stores such as:

banana
orange
apple
pear
plum
tangerin
raspberry
tomato
melon
.
.
.

Store_1 then is described as 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
Store_2 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 ...

This leaves you with a numerical vector, where you can compute dissimilarity measure such as Euclidean Distance.